# imageview setbackgroundcolor is not working in android

Tags: android, imageview

I asked a question about ui updating in preferencelistfragment in android.([How to change imageview background color in a preference in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060798/how-to-change-imageview-background-color-in-a-preference-in-android/21224320#21224320))

And it works for android 4.1.2 version. I test it also in 2.3.3, 3.0 and 4.3 android versions and i see that it is not working in these versions. To make question simple, i would like to ask why the code below is not working on these versions:

```
public class SettingsIncomingSearchFragment extends PreferenceListFragment 
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
     <!-- other codes -->
     setBackgroundColor() ;  
     <!-- other codes -->
    }  

private void setBackgroundColor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinearLayout mainlayout ;
    LinearLayout sublayout ;
    View view ;
    ImageView img ;
    SharedPreferences sp ;
    sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);

       LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rectangle_layout, null);

        mainlayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rectangle_main_layout_ll);

        sublayout = (LinearLayout)mainlayout.findViewById(R.id.rectangle_layout_ll);    

        String defValue = null ;      
        defValue = sp.getString("incomingsearchbackgroundcolor", String.valueOf(Color.BLACK));
        if(defValue != null)
        {
        img = (ImageView)sublayout.findViewById(R.id.iv_priority);
        img.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(defValue));

        }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any error while running in those versions?

Comment: No, there is no error.